# How to filter by user or all users in same viewset in Django REST framework

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

I am a beginner in Django REST Framework and I want to ask how I can (and if at all possible) filter listings by user id or return all listings if user id is not set as a query parameter. Also, each user should be able to edit or delete only their own listings, but be able to see the listings of other users if the parameter is_listed=true.

Here is the corresponding code:

views.py

```
class ListingViewSet(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    """
     Viewset for API endpoint that implements CRUD operations for listing(cards for sale).
    - To perform listing search for all users use base endpoint (api/listing/).
    - To perform listing search by 'is_listed' use base endpoint with ?is_listed=true/false parameter.
    - To perform listing search for specific user use base endpoint with ?user_id=<user_id> parameter.
    - To perform PUT or PATCH use base endpoint with /<listing_id> parameter.
    """

    queryset = Listing.objects.all().order_by('id')
    serializer_class = ListingSerializer
    permission_classes = [permissions.IsAuthenticated]
    filter_backends = [DjangoFilterBackend]
    filterset_class = ListingFilter

    def get_queryset(self):

        user = self.request.query_params.get('user_id', None)

        if user:
            if [IsOwner()]:
                return self.queryset.filter(user=user)

        return self.queryset

    def perform_create(self, serializer):
        serializer.save(user=self.request.user)
```

urls.py

```
urlpatterns = [
    path('', views.ListingViewSet.as_view({'get': 'list', 'post': 'create'}), name='listing'),
    path('<int:pk>/', views.ListingViewSet.as_view(
        {'get': 'retrieve', 'put': 'update', 'delete': 'destroy',
         'patch': 'partial_update'}), name='listing_detail'),
]
```

serializers.py

```
class ListingSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    card_name = serializers.CharField(read_only=True, source='card.yugioh_card')
    card_set_id = serializers.IntegerField(read_only=True, source='card.set.id')
    user_name = serializers.CharField(read_only=True, source='user.username')

    class Meta:
        model = Listing
        fields = ['id', 'card', 'card_name', 'card_set_id', 'user', 'user_name', 'price', 'condition', 'quantity',
                  'is_listed', 'is_sold']
        read_only_fields = ['id', 'user']
        ordering_fields = ['id']
```

permissions.py

```
from rest_framework import permissions


class IsOwner(permissions.BasePermission):
    """"
    This Permission class Check if the user making the request is the creator of the listing

    """

    def has_object_permission(self, request, view, obj):
        return obj.user == request.user
```

filters.py

```
from django_filters import rest_framework as filters
from .models import Listing


class ListingFilter(filters.FilterSet):
    is_listed = filters.BooleanFilter(
        field_name='is_listed',
        lookup_expr='exact',
        label='Search by is_listed (true or false)',
    )

    class Meta:
        model = Listing
        fields = ['is_listed']
```

At the moment I can list all the listings, as well as filter by user id, but the logged in user sees all the listings of others and not only those that are_listed=true

Edited:

Sorry for the omission. This is the model:

```
class Listing(models.Model):
    CONDITION_CHOICES = [
        ('poor', 'Poor'),
        ('played', 'Played'),
        ('good', 'Good'),
        ('excellent', 'Excellent'),
        ('near_mint', 'Near Mint'),
        ('mint', 'Mint'),
    ]
    CONDITION_LENGTH = max(len(c[0]) for c in CONDITION_CHOICES)

    card = models.ForeignKey(
        YugiohCardInSet,
        on_delete=models.CASCADE,
    )

    user = models.ForeignKey(
        User,
        on_delete=models.CASCADE,
    )

    price = models.FloatField()

    condition = models.CharField(
        max_length=CONDITION_LENGTH,
        choices=CONDITION_CHOICES,
    )

    quantity = models.IntegerField(
        default=1,
        validators=[
            validators.MinValueValidator(1),
            validators.MaxValueValidator(9999),
        ]
    )

    is_listed = models.BooleanField(
        default=True
    )

    is_sold = models.BooleanField(
        default=False
    )

    def __str__(self):
        return f'{self.card.yugioh_card.card_name}'
```

I am trying to achieve the following:

The listing is createable only by authenticated users.

The listing can be listed and delisted by its owner.

The delisted ones cannot be seen by other users.

Listings are listed by default on creation.

Allow the frontend to query for unlisted, listed or all items

Comment: So how does the model looks like? Can you also make it more clear *what* you aim to achieve, not much *how* you are trying to achieve it. It is currently not entirely clear. So you should see the `is_listed` ones for the one you are not an owner from, and all items of your own user?

Answer (score 0):

Shouldn't you filter by `user__id` / `user__pk` or `user__username` (if user_id is a username)?:

```py
    def get_queryset(self):

        user_id = self.request.query_params.get('user_id', None)

        if user_id:
            if [IsOwner()]:
                return self.queryset.filter(user__id=user_id)
        return self.queryset
```